# What are these bricks with filled interior and holes/tubes going through?

Tags: piece-information, part-identification

I recently bought at haul and found a bunch of these regular sized bricks. Can anyone identify the for me?

They are 2x4 bricks, but with holes in the side of the bricks:

[image: Bricks with holes]
From: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Atc7p.jpg

It says Lego on the stud, but no part numbers are to be found anywhere, so I guess they are old.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They were used until 1990 for trains, the holes are there to stick in the wheels.

This is the part: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=7049b
And these (for example) were the wheels: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=wheel2a

Comment: you mean the 1970's, right ?

Comment: Makes sense as there was also wheels and tracks in the haul. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome.
@Stephane, no I mean the 1990's, it was still in basic building sets in the late 1980's and the early 1990's.

Comment: oh, I remember them in the early 80's.

Comment: @Laz75 According to the BL page you posted, it seems most of these kits with these parts were released in the 70s, with only a tiny handful of kits in the 90s having these in them.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 you're absolutely right, that's why I wrote "until"!

The white ones though, the ones in the picture, are actually only from the 1960s amd 1970s, you're right.